# Definition of subcoalgebra over a commutative ring

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Let $k$ be commutative ring and $(C, \Delta)$ be a coalgebra over $k$. Let $D$ be a $k$-submodule of $C$.

Notes I'm reading give the following definition:

> $D$ is called subcoalgebra of $C$ if the comultiplication $\Delta: C
>  \to C \otimes C$ restricts to a mapping $$\Delta\vert _D: D \to D
>  \otimes D$$

However, this seems a bit odd to me. Indeed, in general the inclusion $i: D \otimes D \to C \otimes C$ need not be injective so it might not be possible to view $D\otimes D \subseteq C \otimes C$.

What would be the appropriate definition in this context? I see several options:

(1) Assume that we work with flat modules (for example, vector spaces) so that the above makes sense. This seems too restrictive.

(2) Ask that $D$ itself is a coalgebra such that the inclusion $j: D \hookrightarrow C$ is a morphism of coalgebras.

Which definition (if any of these) is the one I should use?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the third version: isn't the restriction $\Delta|_D$ equal to $\Delta\circ j$ by definition?

Comment: @AlexanderBetts Fair point. Seems like I should get my coffee :)

Comment: What is an important example of a (should be) subcoalgebra $D$ where $j : D \hookrightarrow C$ is injective but $j \otimes j : D \otimes D \rightarrow C \otimes C$ is not?

Comment: @MarkWildon The question that has to be answered first is what a subcoalgebra should be...

Comment: It should be quotient algebra in the opposite category, should not it?

Comment: @Mark Wildon, an example could be the one posted in my answer: take the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $C=\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and its submodule $D$,generated by $(2,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  Then, the "inclusion" $D \otimes _\mathbb{Z} D \rightarrow C \otimes_\mathbb{Z} C$ is not injective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised nobody has answered yet so let me state (what seems to me to be) the obvious: (2) is the only reasonable definition of sub-coalgebra which makes sense in general. Said differently you want $\Delta:D\rightarrow C\otimes C$ to factor through $D\otimes D \rightarrow C\otimes C$. The definition in your notes is either an oversight or an abuse of language, I'd say.

As მამუკა ჯიბლაძე suggests, coalgebras in $R$-mod are the same as algebras in $R-mod^{op}$, and you don't require the latter map to be injective in the same way that for a quotient algebra $A\rightarrow B$ you don't usually require $A\otimes A\rightarrow B\otimes B$ to be surjective as well (why would you ?). Of course for algebras over a commutative ring this is automatically true, but it's not true for symmetric monoidal categories whose tensor product is not right exact, which is exactly what happens for $R-mod^{op}$.

The downside is that the coalgebra structure on a sub-coalgebra might not be uniquely determined, i.e. it is possible to have two different coalgebra structures on $D$ for which the inclusion $D\rightarrow C$ is a coalgebra map. In other words, the factorisation of the map $D\rightarrow C\otimes C$ might not be unique. Somewhat related, if $C$ is not flat then its category of comodules might not be abelian.

See e.g. Wischnewsky, [On linear representations of affine groups. I.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102868049) for a reference where this is carefully phrased.

Answer (score 4):

You are right.
In the case of an $R$-submodule $D$ of an $R$-coalgebra $C$, the correct definition for $D$ being a subcoalgebra of $C$ is your definition (2) and not the one posted in your notes. This is standard in the contemporary literature: see for example p.11, sect. 2.7 of [1](https://www.cambridge.org/gr/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/corings-and-comodules?format=PB&isbn=9780521539319).
The definition mentioned in your notes is valid (as you have already mentioned in the OP)  for vector spaces and special cases for $R$-coalgebras (when $D$ is flat or pure as an $R$-submodule for example).

The problem is indeed the one you mention: In general, the restriction of the comultiplication of $C$ to $D$, that is $\Delta\vert _D: D \to C \otimes C$, does not necessarily "lift" to a map $\Delta\vert _D: D \to D \otimes D$. This can happen, even in cases in which $\Delta(D)$ is contained inside the image of the canonical map $D\otimes_R D\to C\otimes_R C$.
A relevant example (attributed to Warren Nichols) is the following: Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $C=\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and denote $x=(1,0)$, and $z=(0,1)$. A comultiplication $\Delta:C\to C\otimes_\mathbb{Z} C$ is defined by $\Delta(x)=0$ and $\Delta(z)=4x\otimes x$. So $\Delta(z)$ has order $2$ in $C\otimes_\mathbb{Z} C$. Then, let $y=2x$ and take the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule $D=\mathbb{Z}y+\mathbb{Z}z\subset C$. Now, $\Delta(z)=y\otimes y$ and $\Delta(D)$ is contained in the image of $D\otimes_\mathbb{Z} D\to C\otimes_\mathbb{Z} C$ but the restriction $\Delta|_{D}$ does not lift (or: does not factor) to a comultiplication $\Delta:D\to D\otimes_\mathbb{Z} D$, since we can see that any preimage of $y\otimes y$ in $D\otimes_\mathbb{Z} D$ has order $4$.
(This example was first suggested by Nichols in [2](https://www.ams.org/books/conm/006/), p.56 and is also cited as an exercise in [1](https://www.cambridge.org/gr/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/corings-and-comodules?format=PB&isbn=9780521539319)).

**Edit:** Another interesting phenomenon, related to the definition, of an $R$-subcoalgebra (definition (2) of the OP), is the fact that following this, the $R$-subcoalgebra $D$ of the $R$-coalgebra $C$ is not uniquely determined: In other words, the same $R$-submodule may correspond to non-isomorphic subcoalgebras. This has already been mentioned and sufficiently explained in Adrien's answer. I thought it might be interesting to include an example of this "phenomenon" (which is again suggested in [2](https://www.ams.org/books/conm/006/) and cited as an exercise in [1](https://www.cambridge.org/gr/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/corings-and-comodules?format=PB&isbn=9780521539319)):
Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $C=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and make it a coalgebra by setting $g=(1,0)$ to be a grouplike and $x=(0,1)$ to be $g$-primitive. Then, take the submodule $D\subset C$ which is spanned by $g$ and $2x$. So, $D\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus  2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. There are (at least) two different ways to make $D$ into a coalgebra: Either consider $g$ to be a grouplike and $2x$ to be $g$-primitive (this corresponds to the restriction of the original map of $C$ in $D$), or take again $g$ to be grouplike and define
$$
\Delta(2x)=g\otimes(2x)+(2x)\otimes(2x)+(2x)\otimes g \ \ \ and \ \ \ \epsilon(2x)=0
$$
Both options make $D$ into a coalgebra and in both cases one can easily show that the inclusion $D\hookrightarrow C$ is a coalgebra morphism. So, $D$ becomes a $\mathbb{Z}$-subcoalgebra of $C$ in (at least) two different ways. Furthermore, these are not isomorphic to each other, since the second structure has an additional grouplike element; this is $g+(2x)$.

**References:**

1. [Corings and comodules, T. Brzezinski, R. Wisbauer](https://www.cambridge.org/gr/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/corings-and-comodules?format=PB&isbn=9780521539319),
2. [Nichols, W.D., Sweedler, M., Hopf algebras and combinatorics](https://www.ams.org/books/conm/006/), AMS, in: "*Umbral Calculus and Hopf algebras*", Contemp. Math. 6, 49–84 (1982)